# Is it not possible to create blog with content taken only from Github?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am struggling with this for long time. 
Using `gatsby-source-git` plugin I can get all markdown content from the repository using `allMarkdownRemark` in graphQL query - the `allFile` directive is not necessary.

But there are problems with Gatsby approach. In my config I have:

```
{
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'markdown-pages',
        path: `${__dirname}/mdsource`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-git',
      options: {
        name: 'cookie-content',
        remote: 'lets say for now it is some private repo on github',
        branch: 'main',
        patterns: ['en/**', 'images/**'],
      },
    },
```

1. I cannot replace 'mdsource' for '.cache/gatsby-source-git/' because when `gatsby develop` is run such path not exist yet.
2. When I remove reference to `gatsby-source-filesystem` completely from `gatsby-config.js` everything crashes on build and graphQL nodes are not properly read.
3. It is not clearly stated in documentation of gatsby-source plugins but it looks they are not stand-alone plugins and require `gatsby-source-filesystem` to run.
4. Using just `gatsby-source-filesystem` without any additional configuration also broke things.
5. All the files from different sources are imported into one huge graphQl tree and there is no way to distinct in AllMarkdownRemark which markdown file comes from where.

In my `gatsby-node.js` file I have function for creating slugs:

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
    const { createNodeField } = actions;
        if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
            const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: 'mdsource' });
            createNodeField({
                    node,
                    name: 'slug',
                    value: slug,
            });
        }
};
```

After I added github repository as additional source I see this function is wrong but I don't know should I delete it completely or modify.

So to summarize: 
- how to have a blog where all the content data are fetched from Github only?
- what is the difference between creating Page,creating File, and creating Markdown node? Seems like all the content of all pages existing as values in json, so there is no need to have file physically on disk.

Comment: This should be possible by adjusting your GraphQL query. The [`gatsby-source-git`](https://github.com/stevetweeddale/gatsby-source-git) plugin says that it `clones the repo(s) you configure [...], and then sucks the files into the graph as File nodes, as if you'd configured gatsby-source-filesystem on that directory`. If you add the right filters in your GraphQL AllFile query, you should be able to isolate your markdown posts. I can help if you share the repository :)

Comment: everything comes to "right filters". For me it looks like Gatsby is badly designed. Because that mess I gave up on project, which is open-source anyway.  the repository is `https://github.com/Polarisation/cookies.education-content` and you are welcome to help contributing to the project if you wish please contact project owner :)

Comment: I tried to summarize the steps you need to take to source content from an external git repo in my answer below. I hope it helps! Gatsby is not always easy at first, but there's a lot of good resources around and a great community. Don't give up! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any issue with Gatsby or the `gatsby-plugin-git`, but I do understand that the steps to source content from an external git repository can feel difficult when you're starting out.

After taking a look at `gatsby-source-git`'s [README](https://github.com/stevetweeddale/gatsby-source-git), I was able to build a Gatsby site that pulls all markdown from [the repository you provided](https://github.com/Polarisation/cookies.education-content).

Here are the steps I took:

1. Create a Gatsby site based on `gatsby-starter-default`:

```sh
gatsby new my-site
```

2. Install `gatsby-source-git`:

```sh
yarn add gatsby-source-git
```

3. Configure `gatsby-source-git` in `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // other plugins go here...
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-git`,
      options: {
        name: `cookie-education`,
        remote: `https://github.com/Polarisation/cookies.education-content.git`,
        // this pattern pulls everything in the `en` directory
        patterns: `en/**`,
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

When running `gatsby-develop`, you should be able to query the posts with GraphQL (you can try this out with the GraphiQL Explorer at http://localhost:8000/___graphql):

```
query AllMarkdownFromGit {
  allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "cookie-education"}, extension: {eq: "md"}}) {
    nodes {
      name
      internal {
        type
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. Use Gatsby's [`createPages`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages) API in `gatsby-node.js` to create a page for each sourced file. It could look something like this:

```js
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  // Query for markdown nodes to use in creating pages.
  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "cookie-education"}, extension: {eq: "md"}}) {
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  // Handle errors
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }
  // Create pages for each markdown file.
  const pageTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/page.js`)
  result.data.allFile.nodes.forEach(({ node }) => {
    const path = node.name
    createPage({
      path,
      component: pageTemplate,
      // In your blog post template's graphql query, you can use pagePath
      // as a GraphQL variable to query for data from the markdown file.
      context: {
        pagePath: path,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

5. Finally, you'll need to create a page template that pulls and renders each file's Markdown content.

Of course, you'll want to adjust this to your needs, and to the site you want to build. The docs on [Creating and Modifying Pages](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/) are a good place to start learning!